# Does PySpark run operation out-of-sequence due to optimization?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, databricks, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm confused about the result my code is giving me. Here is the code I wrote:

```
def update_cassandra(df : DataFrame, aggr: str):
 aggr_map_dict = {
        'Giornaliera' : 'day',
        'Settimanale' : 'week',
        'Bi-Settimanale' : 'bi_week',
        'Mensile': 'month'
    }
    
    max_min_dates = df.agg(F.max(df['data']), F.min(df['data'])).collect()[0]
    upper_date = max_min_dates[0]
    lower_date = max_min_dates[1]
    df = (df.select('data', 'punto_di_interesse', 'id_telco', 'presenze', 'presenze_uniche', 'presenze_00_06','presenze_06_08', 'presenze_08_10', 'presenze_10_12', 'presenze_12_14', 'presenze_14_16', 'presenze_16_18', 'presenze_18_20', 'presenze_20_22', 'presenze_22_24')
                )
    print('contenuto del csv')
    display(df.where(F.col('punto_di_interesse')== 'CC - Neapolis'))
    
    telco_day_aggr = read_from_cassandra_dev(f'telco_{aggr_map_dict[aggr]}_aggr').where(F.col('data').between(lower_date,upper_date))
    
    if telco_day_aggr.count() == 0:
        telco_day_aggr = create_empty_df()
    print('telco_day_aggr as is')
    
    display(telco_day_aggr.where(F.col('punto_di_interesse')== 'CC - Neapolis'))
    
    union_df = df.union(telco_day_aggr)
    print('unione del AS-IS e del csv')
    display(union_df.where(F.col('punto_di_interesse')== 'CC - Neapolis'))
    
    output_df = (union_df.groupBy('data', 'punto_di_interesse', 'id_telco')
                 .agg(
                    F.sum('presenze').alias('presenze'),
                    F.sum('presenze_uniche').alias('presenze_uniche'),
                    F.sum('presenze_00_06').alias('presenze_00_06'),
                    F.sum('presenze_06_08').alias('presenze_06_08'),
                    F.sum('presenze_08_10').alias('presenze_08_10'),
                    F.sum('presenze_10_12').alias('presenze_10_12'),
                    F.sum('presenze_12_14').alias('presenze_12_14'),
                    F.sum('presenze_14_16').alias('presenze_14_16'),
                    F.sum('presenze_16_18').alias('presenze_16_18'),
                    F.sum('presenze_18_20').alias('presenze_18_20'),
                    F.sum('presenze_20_22').alias('presenze_20_22'),
                    F.sum('presenze_22_24').alias('presenze_22_24')
                    )
                )
    
    return output_df

aggregate_df = aggregate_table(df_daily, 'Giornaliera')
write_on_cassandra_dev(aggregate_df, 'telco_day_aggr')
```

What I expect to achieve is to create a sort of update for cassandra, becouse the cassandra drivers. So the operation in my head are like this:

1. read from blob storage the csv and store it in a dataframe (the df variable, input of the method)
2. with max and min dates of this csv file, query the table in cassandra and save it in another variable
3. concatenate the two dataframe
4. summing up with the groupby
5. write on cassandra the new dataframe overwriting the existing rows with the new ones

it seems to me that, some how, what is in the dataframe "df" is written before I can read "telco_day_aggr" and that the union and grupby part are ininfluent. In other words on my cassandra table there is present only the content of df.

I can provide additional information if needed.

Comment: just guessing - would it be possible that the value `telco_day_aggr.count()` results in 0 causing it to create an empty dataframe and thus in turn causing the df_union to have only df records ?

Comment: I need to run the code multiple times. the first time the cassandra table is actually empty and that empty dataframe is just there for foult proofing. the second time the cassandra table contains the right data, but on the successive run it seems to have already be overwritten with data in the df dataframe even if no write operation should had happen.